# Enabling authoryear citation style with urlbst

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, urlbst

I like how [`urlbst`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/urlbst)  handles preprints and DOIs in the bibliography. However, I noticed that none of the default urlbst bibliography styles are capable of producing author-year citations. Whenever I try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[sort, authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainurl}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\begin{document}

One \cite{Colmsee2015}  to \cite{Ghrist2018} serve

\bibliography{foobiblio}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error

```
Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
```

If I instead go for numerical citation, everything goes smoothly.

**Is there a quick way to modify, say `plainurl.bst`, so that it supports author-year citations?**

If needed, this is my `foobiblio.bib` file

```
@Unpublished{Ghrist2018,
  author        = {Robert Ghrist and Rachel Levanger and Huy Mai},
  title         = {Persistent Homology and {E}uler Integral Transforms},
  year          = {2018},
  abstract      = {The Euler calculus -- an integral calculus based on Euler characteristic as a valuation on constructible functions -- is shown to be an incisive tool for answering questions about injectivity and invertibility of recent transforms based on persistent homology for shape characterization.},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eprint        = {1804.04740},
  primaryclass  = {math.AT},
}

@Article{Colmsee2015,
  author    = {Colmsee, Christian and Beier, Sebastian and Himmelbach, Axel and Schmutzer, Thomas and Stein, Nils and Scholz, Uwe and Mascher, Martin},
  journal   = {Molecular Plant},
  title     = {{BARLEX:} the Barley Draft Genome Explorer},
  year      = {2015},
  issn      = {1674-2052},
  month     = {Jun},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {964-966},
  volume    = {8},
  day       = {01},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.molp.2015.03.009},
  groups    = {Barley genomics and phenomics},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `urlbst` distribution is really a distribution of the *script* which modifies `.bst` files, with a few pre-convered BST files included for convenience.

This is a Perl script (sorry – it was a long time ago), and can be used like this (presuming you have Perl installed on your machine):

```
% kpsewhich chicago.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/chicago/chicago.bst
% ./urlbst /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/chicago/chicago.bst chicagourl.bst
```

The first command is to find out where the currently-installed `chicago.bst` actually is.  The second command converts that `.bst` file into a new one called `chicagourl.bst`.

If I take your MWE and substitute

```
\bibliographystyle{chicagourl}
```

Then I get:

[image: MWE output]

The script isn't guaranteed to work on every BST file – it's rather heuristic – but should work OK on ones which look more-or-less like the standard ones.

Comment: I should have read the `urlbst` README file more carefully... Thanks!